# How to generate a Output in the console for selenium

Tags: selenium, testng

I have run a script on eclipse using selenium for facebook login page 
Now I want to make a test case report for same in the console output, Can you please help me out from this. how could I make report in selenium for test cases

Comment: What you have tried so far to generate the report ?

Comment: I have studied about the tool TestNG for Reporting, but it seems bit complex and not even know how it operate

Comment: so you want to configure TestNG ? note that It will generate report in HTML format along with console output.

Comment: not exactly TestNG I can configure this too,  but if there is any other method to generate the report (simplest) then you can even that suggests me

Comment: You can use TestNG as a testing framework , in which there is one IResult interface is present which will help you to create a modified report , moreover you can go with apache POI for report in excel format etc.

Comment: okay i will try thank you

Comment: use apache log4j

Answer (score 1):

You can generate Your own report in several ways:

1. try out [ExtentReports](http://extentreports.com/) this is an easy to You step/test results tracker/reports, You can even setup Your own server to host test results,
2. If you're just trying to export results to You could implement testNg interface, and count Your passed, skipped, or whatever You need tests. Just include in class where You call Your driver and system stuff, here is my example:

   ```
   public interface ITestListener extends ITestNGListener {

     void onTestStart(ITestResult result);

     public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result);

     public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result);

     public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result);

     public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result);

     public void onStart(ITestContext context);

     public void onFinish(ITestContext context);
   }
   ```

Am using combination of this two methods, and its proven to me as a success.

On that topic here was similar question/and answer, check this link for [testNg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50227415/seleniumhow-to-create-test-evidence-report-with-nunit/50228414#50228414)

Hope I could help,

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add a comment because I am still new to this site so,

I use ExtentReports like Kovacic's answer suggests to record test steps.
I also use log4j for recording every detailed information. For example, "page loaded", etc. 
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/